# How to get a simple sample from publilc Twitter streaming API?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to make a small dump of tweets for research purposes, but many tools seem to be overshooting my needs. The only requirement is to have tweets containing specific words on a local machine.

As for Python implementations, [`python-twitter`](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) has `twitter-stream-sample` tool, but it dumps only the message itself without meta data. This and other packages, like `tweethon`, also lack documentation and examples on working with the streaming API.

The language isn't important, and command line tools would also be very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, for example the [Requests API](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests). The documentation (see the link) has some basic explanation how to use it with streaming API. You will have to setup OAuth, which is also described in Requests docs.

Then you setup the request:

```
    track = 'the' # <-- whatever keyword you want to track
    payload = {'language': 'en', 'track': track,
               'stringify_friend_ids': 'true'}
    url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"
    r = requests.get(url=url, auth=oauth, stream=True, params=payload)
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        # process the lines
```

The result is json. Don't forget to close the stream:

```
    ...
    finally:
            print("Closing connection...")
            r.connection.close()
```

Edit: This is the authorization code:

```
REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"


def setup_oauth():
    """Authorize your app via identifier."""
    # Request token
    oauth = OAuth1(TW_API_KEY, client_secret=TW_API_SECRET)
    r = requests.post(url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
    credentials = parse_qs(r.content)

    resource_owner_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    resource_owner_secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

    # Authorize
    authorize_url = AUTHORIZE_URL + resource_owner_key
    print('Please go here and authorize: ' + authorize_url)

    verifier = raw_input('Please input the verifier: ')
    oauth = OAuth1(TW_API_KEY,
                   client_secret=TW_API_SECRET,
                   resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                   resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
                   verifier=verifier)

    # Finally, Obtain the Access Token
    r = requests.post(url=ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
    credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
    token = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

    return token, secret


def get_oauth():
    oauth = OAuth1(TW_API_KEY,
                   client_secret=TW_API_SECRET,
                   resource_owner_key=TW_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                   resource_owner_secret=TW_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return oauth
```

Comment: Thanks, Mirek. I got it all but OAuth authorization. Do I need something like this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples , because Requests mention only headers?

Comment: The oauth is also available via Requests. I added my code to the answer.

Comment: much obliged. Where do functions `parse_qs` and `OAuth1` come from?

Comment: This is from the Requests: from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1 and the other one is from from urllib.parse import parse_qs. I think you will also need from past.builtins.misc import raw_input.